# Quantum tunneling of dark energy from black holes

Tags: black-holes, space-expansion, cosmological-inflation, dark-energy, quantum-tunneling

There was an article posted recently suggesting there is a very deep connection between dark energy and black holes.

https://phys.org/news/2019-09-black-holes-dark-energy.html

I was thinking this morning that if one can make a case that black hole interiors can trap dark energy and we accept that quantum effects can allow for tunneling from the black holes interior, can a seemingly counterintuitive situation exist where a connection to our very early Big Bang state exist and allow black holes to facilitate a “leaking” of our very early universe.  E.g. leaking dark energy from black hole interiors are a mechanism for cosmic expansion?